# What does "ku" or "kU" mean with regards to procuring ICs? (not about RF)

Tags: integrated-circuit, terminology, buying, units

**NB:** *This is not referring to RF subject matter.* 
I'm seeing 1ku and 10ku on procurement documentation for purchasing motor driver ICs (TI DRV8811 and some others). Does this mean "one-thousand units"? 
 Sometimes I also see it written as kU (10kU) in the same context.

Comment: I would assume it's one thousand units.

Comment: I would assume the same, but I'm a beginner.  I've never seen this terminology before, and I feel it's quite industry specific.

Comment: minimum order quantity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1kU refers to 1000 units. 
10kU refers to 10,000 units.

You will often see this on a pricing schedule where the vendor or manufacturer specify pricing based upon committed quantity from the purchaser.

Comment: So something like $0.68|1ku means one needs to buy a minimum of 1000 units to have the price per unit of $0.68?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what that means.

Answer (score 3):

1ku = 1,000 units
10ku = 10,000 units

EE commonly uses the [SI Metric Unit prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) where 'k' is kilo, 1,000